# Error with group by in DB2 - SQLSTATE 42803

Tags: sql, db2

I've got a SQL script and its failing. This is what it looks like:

```
SELECT  P.SOORT,P.TYPEBETALING, P.MIDDELCODE, P.HOEVEELHEID, P.EENHEID, P.BEDRAG,P.MIDDEL 
FROM DAAO01.BETALINGEN as A join
     DAAO01.KLANTEN P
     on p.KLANT_ID = 1
GROUP BY P.TYPEBETALING
ORDER BY P.TYPEBETALING
```

When I execute this I get an error:

```
COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN THE SELECT LIST IS NOT VALID. SQLCODE=-122, SQLSTATE=42803, DRIVER=4.18.60
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite difficult to tell what you're trying to do without seeing your data.

But the error is saying that you have not specified how you are going to deal with the rest of the fields in your Group by aggregation:

P.SOORT, P.MIDDELCODE, P.HOEVEELHEID, P.EENHEID, P.BEDRAG, P.MIDDEL

If they're numbers, then you could sum them or take the avg etc.

If they're strings, then you either need to group by them or remove them from your selection.